i am able to send the request to spring boot soap endpoint using soap UI and post man, but while trying from SAP getting error 500
I am able to send the request to spring boot soap endpoint using soap UI and post man, but while trying from SAP, I am getting 500 error and getting the below error in Java code


<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="targeturl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="targeturl" targetNamespace="targeturl">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns="targeturl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.hp.com/prs/priceupdate">
<xs:element name="rootelement">
xsd file content i removed from here, xsd file content are good 
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="RegisterResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="response" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="RegisterResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:RegisterResponse" name="RegisterResponse"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="WebServicePort">
<wsdl:operation name="Register">
<wsdl:output message="tns:RegisterResponse" name="RegisterResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="WebServicePortSoap12" type="tns:WebServicePort">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Register">
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:output name="RegisterResponse">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WebServicePortSoap11" type="tns:WebServicePort">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Register">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:output name="RegisterResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="WebServicePortService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:WebServicePortSoap12" name="WebServicePortSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://hostname:7002/ws"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port binding="tns:WebServicePortSoap11" name="WebServicePortSoap11">
<soap:address location="http://hostname:7002/ws"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>




SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source

where I am doing mistake?
I extracted header from Postman and passed same header from sap.
"Request Headers": {
    "content-type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "host": "hostname",
    "content-length": "5504"
  }


added wsdl as well here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
